# Which phone has got high sales in each year?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql. How to write the query to find the phone name that has got highest sales(highest number of Sold_out in each year)

```
--------------------------------------------
Phone      Sold_out      Month      Year
--------------------------------------------
iphone      3            Jan-15     2015
iphone      10           Feb-15     2015
samsung     4            March-15   2015
Lava        14           June-16    2016
Lenova      8            July-16    2016
Lenova      10           Sep-16     2016 
Motorola    8            Jan-17     2017
Nokia       7            Jan-17     2017
Nokia       3            Feb-17     2017
--------------------------------------------
```

The result I need is

```
-----------------------------
year      Phone      sales
-----------------------------
2015      iphone     13
2016      lenova     18
2017      Nokia      10
-----------------------------
```

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, please add more details around your attempted solutions

Comment: What if two brand have same equally high sales in same year? then which one should output ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the derived table the total sales are calculated at ( year,phone ) combination. Once the total sales are calculated all the top rows( rank = 1 by sales ) should be identified for each year. By using correlated sub-queries and having clause the first row is identified from each group( year ) and displayed as final output.

```
SELECT year,phone, sales_per_year
  FROM
      (
      SELECT year,phone,SUM(sold_out) AS sales_per_year
        FROM sales
      GROUP BY year,phone          
      ) o
 GROUP BY year,phone
 HAVING (
           SELECT COUNT(*)
             FROM 
                   (
                      SELECT year,phone,SUM(sold_out) AS sales_per_year
                        FROM sales
                      GROUP BY year,phone                          
                    ) i  
           WHERE i.year = o.year             
             AND i.sales_per_year > o.sales_per_year 
          ) < 1          
ORDER BY year,phone,sales_per_year DESC
```

Check the sql fiddle link
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff096e/14

Comment: Please try not to encourage bad questions that show no attempt in solving the problem.

Comment: mysql supports ROW_NUMBER() ?

Comment: Why are you guys discouraging the answers?

Comment: I tried.My table name is analyse. I didn't get answer.

Comment: What is the result you are getting?

Comment: are u able to see -2 on left hand side of my ans? click on up arrow and there is atick below that...

Comment: I clicked the up arrow and tried to make it positive vote but it is not changing